# Matlab: How to vectorize a nested loop over a 2D set of vectors

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, vectorization

I have a function in the following form:

```
function Out = DecideIfAPixelIsWithinAnEllipsoidalClass(pixel,means,VarianceCovarianceMatrix)  
   ellipsoid = (pixel-means)'*(VarianceCovarianceMatrix^(-1))*(pixel-means);  
   if ellipsoid <= 1
      Out = 1;
   else
      Out = 0;
   end
end
```

I am doing remote-sensing processes with matlab and I want to classify a LandSatTM images.This picture has 7 bands and is 2048*2048.So I stored them in 3 dimentinal 2048*2048*7 matrix.in this function means is a 7*1 matrix calculated earlier using the sample of the class in a function named ExtractStatisticalParameters and VarianceCovarianceMatrix is a 7*7 matrix in fact you see that:

```
ellipsoid = (pixel-means)'*(VarianceCovarianceMatrix^(-1))*(pixel-means);
```

is the equation of an ellipsoid.My problem is that each time you can pass a single pixel(it is a 7*1 vector where each row is the value of the pixel in a seperated band) to this function so I need to write a loop like this:

```
for k1=1:2048  
   for k2=1:2048  
      pixel(:,1)=image(k1,k2,:); 
      Out = DecideIfAPixelIsWithinAnEllipsoidalClass(pixel,means,VarianceCovarianceMatrix);  
   end  
end
```

and you know it will take alot of time and energy of the system.Can you suggest me a way to reduce the pressure applied on the systam?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for loops!

```
pMinusMean = bsxfun( @minus, reshape( image, [], 7 ), means' ); %//' subtract means from all pixes
iCv = inv( arianceCovarianceMatrix );
ell = sum( (pMinusMean * iCv ) .* pminusMean, 2 ); % note the .* the second time!
Out = reshape( ell <= 1, size(image(:,:,1)) ); % out is 2048-by-2048 logical image
```

#### Update:

After a (somewhat heated) debate in the comments below I add a correction made by [Rody Oldenhuis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156379/matlab-how-to-vectorize-a-nested-loop-over-a-2d-set-of-vectors/17156570?noredirect=1#comment24837276_17156570):

```
pMinusMean = bsxfun( @minus, reshape( image, [], 7 ), means' ); %//' subtract means from all pixes
ell = sum( (pMinusMean / varianceCovarianceMatrix ) .* pminusMean, 2 ); % note the .* the second time!
Out = reshape( ell <= 1, size(image(:,:,1)) );
```

The key issue in this change is that Matlab's `inv()` is poorly implemented and it is **best** to use [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) and [`mrdivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) (operators `/` and `\`) instead.

Comment: ...did you just use `inv()` to solve a linear system? Near the top of `doc inv`: "In practice, it is seldom necessary to form the explicit inverse of a matrix. A frequent misuse of `inv` arises when solving the system of linear equations `Ax = b`. One way to solve this is with `x = inv(A)*b`. A better way, from both an execution time and numerical accuracy standpoint, is to use the matrix division operator `x = A\b`. This produces the solution using Gaussian elimination, without forming the inverse. See `mldivide` (`\`) for further information."

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis `inv` is NOT used for solving systems of equations in this question, it is used as the covariance matrix of a gaussian (ellipsoid).

Comment: euhmmm...so? What prevents you from writing `sum( pMinusMean/varianceCovarianceMatrix .* pminusMean, 2)`?

Comment: Oh well, in that case, let's just use `pi = 3` from now on shall we, that's far more readable than writing all those digits all the time... Who cares about all those digits anyway, right? Suggesting someone use `inv()` is teaching that person bad habits; you really ***NEVER*** need or should use `inv()`.

Comment: [Never](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/05/16/purpose-of-inv/)? Let's not go crazy.

Comment: @Shai - ah yes, the `bsxfun` you love so much :)

Comment: @DangKhoa I run `bsxfun` in a loop, at the background - just for fun

Comment: @Shai that wouldn't be very efficient then, would it? :)

Comment: @horchler: No, really, ***NEVER***. Those four reasons Loren mentions are easily nullified: 1. teaching proper use of `mrdivide`, `mldivide`, `lu()`, `qr()` etc. (and *why*) is actually much more valuable and durable. 2. you could just deprecate `inv()`, or 3. you could make `inv() ` nothing more than a wrapper around `mrdivide`/`mldivide`. 4. just use `A\eye(size(A))` if you **really** insist. But for this particular question, `iCv` is used for no other purpose than to solve a post-multiplied system (`X*A = B`), so why on Earth wouldn't you use the best tool available for that (`mrdivide`) ?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis - I updated my answer to reflect your argumnets.

Comment: @Shai: Well that wasn't really my intention, but thanks :) It's not that it's "poorly implemented", it's just that no algorithms exist that are as fast and accurate as the ones you can use to compute the products `inv(A)*x` or `x*inv(A)`. Sorry if I come off a bit strong about this issue, but when you see people use `i` or `j` as a variable name, what would you do? :) I'm saying that it's nice to implement a bubble-sort or bogosort for educational reasons once or twice, but really, in the end what you should *use* and *teach* is quicksort (and similar) -- same with `inv()`.

Comment: You comment wasn't about `A*X = B`, but rather that one should NEVER use `inv`. I don't don't like blanket statements. As you say, teaching new users why things work one way or another and what the trade-offs are is better than just saying "NEVER." As is mentioned, `inv` is a simple function that has speed advantages in some cases. Precision down to `eps` is not always desired as long as one understands the numerics of a particular problem. "Best" does not always mean most accurate. `trace(A\eye(size(A)))` takes 50% longer than `trace(inv(A))` for large random matrices on my machine.

Comment: @horchler: name 1 case, any case, where you think you *need* `inv()`, and mention why, and I'll come up with a better alternative.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Suppose you have a 3x3 affine transformation relating image I to image J such that `imtransform(I, H) == J`. How would you find the inverse transform relating `J` to `I`?

Comment: @Shai: Do you mean something like [this](http://negativeprobability.blogspot.de/2011/11/affine-transformations-and-their.html)? Sure looks like an ordinary linear system to me there...