# Matlab's `inv` function

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

After (quite a lengthy) discussion with Rody Oldenhuis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156379/matlab-how-to-vectorize-a-nested-loop-over-a-2d-set-of-vectors/17156570#comment24836840_17156570) and another discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263873/singularity-for-inverse-matrix#comment25036523_17263873), I think it is best to make it a formal question:

1. Why should one avoid using Matlab's `inv()`?
2. What better alternatives exists for `inv` for different use cases?

Comment: related question: [Why is Matlab's inv slow and inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419580/)

Comment: another related question is: [Singularity for inverse matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263873/singularity-for-inverse-matrix)

Comment: A relevant post on [Loren's blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/05/16/purpose-of-inv/).

Comment: In the case of linear systems you can find on the [FEX: Don't let that INV go past your eyes; to solve that system, FACTORIZE!](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24119-dont-let-that-inv-go-past-your-eyes-to-solve-that-system-factorize). This link has also a good publishable demo.

Comment: I'd be interested in cases where `inv` is sufficiently accurate and actually faster than other common methods (I'm not talking about solving linear systems). I think that there's a strange sort of orthodoxy surrounding `inv` because it can be easily misused. Many of Matlab's methods are a tradeoff between precision and speed and require a good level of understanding in order to use properly, i.e., the ODE suite. It would be nice to bring back some subtlety.