# Checking which rows switched given an original and an altered matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, permutation, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for awhile and was hoping to get some insight.
Suppose you have matrix A, then you switched rows until you ended up with matrix B;

```
A = [1 3 1;
3 2 1;
2 3 1;];

B = [3 2 1;
1 3 1;
2 3 1;];

invA =

    0.0000   -1.0000    1.0000
   -1.0000   -1.0000    2.0000
    3.0000    5.0000   -7.0000


invB =

   -1.0000    0.0000    1.0000
   -1.0000   -1.0000    2.0000
    5.0000    3.0000   -7.0000
```

How would I document these row switches?. I'm ultimately trying to alter the inverse of B to match with the inverse of A. My conclusion was that given 2 rows switched (aka between rows 1 and 2), the end result of the inverse would be identical except for switching the **columns** of (1 and 2) of the inverse B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite a basic algebra question.
You can write your matrix `B` as a product of a [permutation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) `P` and `A`:

```
B = PA;
```

(in your example: `P = [0 1 0;1 0 0;0 0 1];`).
Now you can invert `B`:

```
inv( B ) = inv( PA )
```

The inverse of a product is

```
         = inv(A) * inv(P)
```

Since matrix `P` is a **permutation** matrix: `inv(P) = P.'`. Thus

```
         = inv(A) * P.'
```

That is, `inv(B) = inv(A) * P.'` which means that you apply the permutation `P` to the columns of `inv(A)`.

Note that a permutation `P` can represent more than a single switch between rows, moreover, permutations can be multiplies to account for repeated switching of rows.

---

An important comment: I use `inv` in this answer to denote the inverse of a matrix. However, when running Matlab and numerically inverting matrices [it is un-recommended to use `inv` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271769/matlabs-inv-function) explicitly.

Comment: oh, permutations interesting. They are something I'm unfamiliar with. How did you come up with your permultation in the first part? And is the end result you altering the inverse of A the original matrix?

Comment: @user3509716 please read the [linked wiki page about permutation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) this will give you the basics and provide pointers for further reading. `inv(A)` in my answer is the inverse of the original `A` matrix.